# How do I handle rollback in case of failure using handlers in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I wrote below yml file which will install the SSM and cloudwatch agent but I want to rollback the installation in case of any failures during the installation. I tried use FAIL but not working..Please advise..

```
---
# tasks file for SSMAgnetInstall
- name: status check
  command: systemctl status amazon-ssm-agent
  register: s_status
- debug:
    msg: "{{ s_status  }}"

- name: Get CPU architecture
  command: getconf LONG_BIT
  register: cpu_arch
  changed_when: False
  check_mode: no
  when: s_status.stdout == ""
  ignore_errors: true

- name: Install rpm file for Redhat Family (Amazon Linux, RHEL, and CentOS) 32/64-bit
  yum:
    name: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/linux_386/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm"
    state: present
  when: s_status.stdout == ""
  become: yes
  ignore_errors: true

- name: cloud status check
  command: systemctl status amazon-cloudwatch-agent
  register: cld_status
  become: yes
- debug:
    msg: "{{ cld_status  }}"

- name: Register to cloud watch service
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  service:
    name: amazon-ssm-agent
    enabled: yes
    state: started

- name: copy the output to a local file
  copy:
    content: "{{ myshell_output.stdout }}"
    dest: "/home/ansible/rama/output.txt"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look at the [the documentation on blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html), more specifically the error handling part. This is the general idea with an oversimplified example, you will have to adapt to your specific case.

The `test.yml` playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - block:

        - name: I am a task that can fail
          debug:
            msg: "I {{ gen_fail | default(false) | bool | ternary('failed', 'succeeded') }}"
          failed_when: gen_fail | default(false) | bool

        - name: I am a task that will never fail
          debug:
            msg: I succeeded

      rescue:

        - name: I am a task in a block played when a failure happens
          debug:
            msg: rescue task

      always:

        - name: I am a task always played whatever happens
          debug:
            msg: always task
```

Played normally (no fail)

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************

TASK [I am a task that can fail] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "I succeeded"
}

TASK [I am a task that will never fail] *************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "I succeeded"
}

TASK [I am a task always played whatever happens] ***************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "always task"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Played forcing a fail

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml -e gen_fail=true

PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************

TASK [I am a task that can fail] ********************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "I failed"
}

TASK [I am a task in a block played when a failure happens] *****************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "rescue task"
}

TASK [I am a task always played whatever happens] ***************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "always task"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=1    ignored=0
```